# What's the purpose of sitting down in Fallout 3?

Tags: fallout-3

The Capital Wasteland is full of chairs, benches and other items that give you the option to sit down.  Is there any in-game situation in which it's better to sit than to stand or crouch?  For example, does sitting increase one or more of your stats?  Or is the option just presented to make the game more realistic?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It's useful only in the very beginning of the game to take the G.O.A.T test.
For the rest of the game is only for fun (not too much though) :)

Comment: Oh, good call!  I forgot about that; after my first game, I started skipping the test altogether.

Comment: There was another place later in the game, in a particular vault under a garage, where it was necessary to sit somewhere in order to progress the plot. (I wouldn't have noticed except that I was curious about whether sitting down had any further use, after seeing this question!)

Answer (score 34):

There's no gameplay purpose to sitting down. It's purely for the purposes of immersion/roleplaying/atmosphere, and for taking nice screenshots.

Answer (score 12):

I sat before talking to the ghoul in the mansion at Point Lookout and he commented on how it was polite to sit.

Answer (score 6):

No purpose except to rest those pixels after a long day of killin stuff in the wasteland!